# swapping two columns in a matrix represented by vector

Tags: c++, matrix, time-complexity, stdvector

I have the following problem:
I have a single vector that represents a 2 dimensional matrix, I have the number of rows and the number of columns and few other stuff that are irrelevant.

```
// A synomon for the type of the grayvalues
typedef unsigned int grayvalue_t;
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<grayvalue_t>::max()<=
              std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(),
              "grayvalue_t maximum should be smaller than size_t maximum");

// Number of rows
size_t _R;
// Number of columns
size_t _C;
// Maximum grayvalue
grayvalue_t _MAX_G;
// Pixels' grayvalues
std::vector<grayvalue_t> _pixels;
```

I'm asked to swap two given rows (given by indices) in O(1), that is not a problem since I can just use memcpy and replace between two continuous blocks of memory, but the problem is that i'm also asked to swap two given columns (again by indices) in O(1) time, but in that case the columns of the matrix aren't continuous blocks of memory in the vector.

```
/// swaps between rows r1 and r2
/// Time complexity: O(1)
void swap_rows(const size_t& r1, const size_t& r2) {

}

/// swaps between columns c1 and c2
/// Time complexity: O(1)
void swap_cols(const size_t& c1, const size_t& c2) {

}
```

Am I missing anything? 
Would like to get some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like a lot of other CS problems, the answer is: one more layer of indirection.

One option is to maintain a map that maps the column index in the matrix to its actual index in your vector. That is, your matrix columns will not always be stored in order, whereas elements of a row will remain contiguous. The map starts out mapping 0 to 0 1 to 1, and so on. To swap two columns you simply swap their entries in the map. If you also need to traverse the whole array row-wise you will need to consult the map about order of columns.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be easy after some changes. Have a good day!